# Add input box in checkout page

Tags: checkout, magento-2.1

I am trying to add an input text box in checkout payment part for customer input the sales id.

[image]

The payment option in the image is just one of the default Magento payment method.

do I need to rewrite the hold payment method or there is other way for this?
All the product in my DB are Virtual Product
so it won't have any shipping form.

I have tried using plugin but it just add into the billing address form which is not what I need.

Does anyone have the answer or some suggestion?